# Save zip file from url C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to save a zip file from a URL that doesn't directly link to the file (like http://website.com/DocMgm/DocMgmServlet?docNum=pce-0011&attachmentType=Archive). When I use the link in the browser it brings up the download file option but I can't seem to get it to work programatically.

When I try to do either method the created zip file produces the following error:

> Can not open file 'C:\temp\PCE-0011.zip' as archive

The url is fake. I don't know the exact relationship between that and the file on the server, I think it works as a redirect to the most current version of the file (it is through a document control system).

Here are the two general ways I've tried:

```
        string ZipURL = "http://website.com/DocMgm/DocMgmServlet?docNum=pce-0011&attachmentType=Archive";
        string SaveURL = "c:\\temp\\PCE-0011.zip";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile(ZipURL, @SaveURL);
```

And:

```
        string url = "http://website.com/DocMgm/DocMgmServlet?docNum=pce-0011&attachmentType=Archive";

        WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        using (Stream input = objResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (FileStream output = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\PCE-0011.zip",
            FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You've said what you tried, but given no indication of what the result was beyond "I can't seem to get it to work." Please give more details, or it's impossible to help you. (I note that you're note disposing of the `WebResponse`, which is bad but *probably* unrelated.)

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between the zip file and the URL if the URL does not point *directly* to the zip file?

Comment: I assume you mean "programmatically", not "problematically"?

Comment: The link to the file you specified does not exists. The page is returning a 404 Not found error.

Comment: @DelegateX I'm guessing it's a fake address.